# B+Tree Node sum

Tags: java, recursion, b-tree

I am trying to sum all the elements of a B+ Tree Node at a certain Depth.

Here is the code:

```
public static int printSumAtD(BTreeNode T, int d) {

    if(d == 0) {
        int sum;

        for (int i = 0; i < T.key.length; i++) {
             sum =  sum + T.key[i];
        }
        return sum;

    } else {
        if(T.isLeaf)
            return 0;
        else{
            for(int i = 0; i < T.n+1; i++) {
                printSumAtD(T.c[i], d-1);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that "sum" would be the sum of each element, however at the end it goes to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to use the return value from your recursive call.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Comment: `sum += printSumAtD(T.c[i], d-1)`, but why this method is called `printSumAtD()` is a mystery. It doesn't print anything.

Comment: Sorry, that is right, It should no be `print`. By the way were in the code I should do `sum += sumAtD(T.c[i], d-1)` I do not know where to initialize `sum`.

Comment: `int sum = 0;` at the top of the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of suggestions for you:

1. in recursive calls you need to consider how you will take the results and reduce them. In your case you are ignoring the return value of the recursive calls.
2. This method should really be inside the `BTreeNode` class so that you can avoid access instance variables `key` and `c` (which should be private and have better names).
3. Get used to using `Stream` and collections for this type of iterative operation rather than traditional iteration.

Putting all that together:

```
class BTreeNode {
    private int value;
    private List<BTreeNode> children;

    public int sumAtDepth(int depth) {
        if (depth == 0)
            return value;
        else if (depth > 0)
            return children.stream()
                .mapToInt(c -> c.sumAtDepth(depth - 1)).sum();
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative depth");
    }
}
```